# how i can set the value of a nested property using the RTTI

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rtti

Check this simplified sample (the real scenario is different), I want to set tne value of a nested property of a object, in this case set the color of the Font for a `TLabel` component to `clRed` using RTTI.

```
var
  p : TRttiProperty;
  p2: TRttiProperty;
  c : TRttiContext;
begin
   c := TRttiContext.Create;
   try
     p := c.GetType(Label1.ClassInfo).GetProperty('Font');
     p2 := c.GetType(p.PropertyType.Handle).GetProperty('Color');
     p2.SetValue(p.PropertyType.AsInstance,clred); //this line is not working
   finally
     c.Free;
   end;
end;
```

also i tried

```
p2.SetValue(Label1,clred);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will work.

```
var
  p : TRttiProperty;
  p2: TRttiProperty;
  c : TRttiContext;
begin
   c := TRttiContext.Create;
   try
     p := c.GetType(Label1.ClassInfo).GetProperty('Font');
     p2 := c.GetType(p.PropertyType.Handle).GetProperty('Color');
     p2.SetValue(p.GetValue(Label1).AsObject,clred); //this line now works.
   finally
     c.Free;
   end;
end;
```

You need to get the Embedded Font from the Label.   TRttiProperty deal with types and not instances.   You need to call `GetValue()` or `SetValue()` to deal with the instance.

Your original code was referencing the type and not the instance.